# Find <p>(paragraph) tag with specific class and extract it's content using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i want to find p tag with class **ft04** between Work Experience and EDUCATION AND TRAINING and extract class text which contains company name from the given html

```
<p class = "ft00">Introduction</p>
<p class = "ft00">John Smith</p>
<p class = "ft02">Email:</p>
<p class = "ft02">Phone Number:</p>
<p class = "ft00">John@gmail.com</p>
<p class = "ft00">Work Experience</p>
<p class = "ft00">27 July 2017</p>
<p class = "ft04">ABC Company</p>
<p class = "ft00">19 May 2018</p>
<p class ="ft04">XYZ Company</p>
<p class = "ft00">EDUCATION AND TRAINING</p>
```

so far i could get is to extract all data between Work Experience and EDUCATION AND TRAINING and it's working properly and the code is given below:-

```
$fexp = $html->find('p[plaintext^=Work Experience]');
$items = array();
 foreach ($fexp as $keye) {

    while ( $keye->nextSibling() ) {
        if ( $keye->nextSibling() == TRUE ) {

         $keye = $keye->nextSibling();
            $varce = $keye->plaintext;



        }
        if ( trim($varce) == "EDUCATION AND TRAINING" ){
            break;
        }
        //$test[] = $collection;
       $items[] = $varce;
        // echo $varce;

}
}
var_dump($items);
```

i am close but can't seem to find out the solution, any help would be appreciated thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code :)

```
$html = '<p class = "ft00">Introduction</p>
<p class = "ft00">John Smith</p>
<p class = "ft02">Email:</p>
<p class = "ft02">Phone Number:</p>
<p class = "ft00">John@gmail.com</p>
<p class = "ft00">Work Experience</p>
<p class = "ft00">27 July 2017</p>
<p class = "ft04">ABC Company</p>
<p class = "ft00">19 May 2018</p>
<p class ="ft04">XYZ Company</p>
<p class = "ft00">EDUCATION AND TRAINING</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$items = array();

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    if (strtolower(trim($p->nodeValue)) == 'work experience') {
        $found = true;
    }
    if (isset($found) && strtolower(trim($p->getAttribute('class'))) == 'ft04') {
        $items[] = $p->nodeValue;
    }
    if (strtolower(trim($p->nodeValue)) == 'education and training') {
        break;
    }
}

print_r($items);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC Company
    [1] => XYZ Company
)
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You could check the class with:

`$keye->getAttribute("class") === "ft04"`

and you could set the `nextSibling()` in the while statement to shorten you code:

`while ($keye = $keye->nextSibling()) {`

When looping through the siblings you check for the classname ft04 and add the `plaintext` to your array `$items`.

You could update your code to:

```
$fexp = $html->find('p[plaintext^=Work Experience]');
$items = array();
foreach ($fexp as $keye) {
    while ($keye = $keye->nextSibling()) {
        if ($keye->plaintext === "EDUCATION AND TRAINING") {
            break;
        }
        if($keye->getAttribute("class") === "ft04") {
            $items[] = $keye->plaintext;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($items);
```

That would give you:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "ABC Company"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "XYZ Company"
}
```